# Writing Array to JSON Using Java and Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to create a JSON structure that looks like this by reading from a csv.

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "udas": [
      {
        "name": "UDF1",
        "dataType": "number",
        "value": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The structure I get is

```
[{
    "firstName": "Michael",
    "lastName": "Dodd"
}, {
    "udas": [{
        "name": "UDF1",
        "dataType": "number",
        "entityCode": 0
    }]
}]
```

Reading from the file is no issue, but formatting the JSON is a problem. How do I get rid of the extra curly braces around the "udas" array?

Here is the code I am using.

```
public class MyTestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String row;
        String[] data = {};
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();      

        try {
            BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("res/mydata.csv"));
            row = csvReader.readLine();
            data = row.split(",");

            csvReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       

        ArrayNode arrayNode = objectMapper.createArrayNode();

        ObjectNode personObjectNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
        personObjectNode.put("firstName", data[0]);
        personObjectNode.put("lastName", data[1]);
        arrayNode.add(personObjectNode);

        ArrayNode udaArrayNode = objectMapper.createArrayNode();

        ObjectNode approvalAuthorityObjectNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
        approvalAuthorityObjectNode.put("name", "UDF1");
        approvalAuthorityObjectNode.put("dataType", "number");
        approvalAuthorityObjectNode.put("entityCode", Integer.parseInt(data[15]));
        udaArrayNode.add(approvalAuthorityObjectNode);

        ObjectNode udaObjectNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();        
        udaObjectNode.putPOJO("udas", udaArrayNode);
        arrayNode.add(udaObjectNode);

        System.out.println(arrayNode.toString());    
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding `udas` to a new `ObjectNode` and that to the `arrayNode`? You should be adding it to the `personObjectNode`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. Is `ObjectNode udaObjectNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();` the statement you are referring to? If I change `arrayNode.add(udaObjectNode);` to `arrayNode.add(udaObjectNode);` I get a JSON that just duplicates the first section `[{"firstName":"Michael","lastName":"Dodd"},{"firstName":"Michael","lastName":"Dodd"}]`.

Comment: Get rid of the whole `udaObjectNode ` section of your code and just `personObjectNode.putPOJO("udas", udaArrayNode);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following change fixed the problem. Thanks, @SotiriosDelimanolis.

```
public class MyTestClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String row;
        String[] data = {};
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();      

        try {
            BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("res/mydata.csv"));
            row = csvReader.readLine();
            data = row.split(",");

            csvReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       

        ArrayNode arrayNode = objectMapper.createArrayNode();

        ObjectNode personObjectNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
        personObjectNode.put("firstName", data[0]);
        personObjectNode.put("lastName", data[1]);
        arrayNode.add(personObjectNode);

        ArrayNode udaArrayNode = objectMapper.createArrayNode();
        ObjectNode approvalAuthorityObjectNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
        approvalAuthorityObjectNode.put("name", "UDF1");
        approvalAuthorityObjectNode.put("dataType", "number");
        approvalAuthorityObjectNode.put("entityCode", Integer.parseInt(data[15]));

        udaArrayNode.add(approvalAuthorityObjectNode);

        personObjectNode.putPOJO("udas", udaArrayNode);

        System.out.println(arrayNode.toString());    
    }
}
```

Now I get the JSON

```
[{
    "firstName": "Michael",
    "lastName": "Dodd",
    "udas": [{
        "name": "UDF1",
        "dataType": "number",
        "entityCode": 0
    }]
}]
```